# Breezejs: Perform search on field in related table

Tags: odata, breeze

I have followed tutorials / videos showing off how to perform a live search on data coming from two entities on the northwind database running on a Microsoft backend.

I have to develop an application that has a `php / mysql` backend so have got hold of the php producer classes to do this. I have connected to a Wordpress DB and it all seems to be working well.

However, my problem is when I try to perform a search on a related table. I have a grid showing author's `displayName` (from the User entity), the `post title` and `date` (from Posts).

```cs
<input type="text" data-ng-model="searchText"/> {{searchText}}
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Author </th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <td>{{post.user.displayName}}</td>
        <td>{{post.date}}</td>
        <td>{{post.title}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the controller (actually the datacontext.js) I have the following to get the data from the server:

```cs
    if (searchText && (searchText = searchText.trim())) {
        log("searching for " + searchText);
        var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('title', 'contains', searchText);               
        query = query.where(pred);

    } else {
        console.log("getting all");
    }

    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success);
```

My problem is with referring to fields in the Predicate correctly. When I run the code searching for just the Posts title Entity as below it works fine.

```cs
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('title', 'contains', searchText);
```

As soon as I change it to the following it stops working. There are no errors in the console as well.

```cs
 var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('title', 'contains', searchText)
            .or('displayname', 'contains', searchText);
```

I have tried several variants of 'displayName' such as 'displayname', 'posts.user.displayname', 'user.displayname' and all those in camelCase as well.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an example in the breeze web page that shows how to query on related properties.

```
// Products in a Category whose name starts with 'S'
var query1 = EntityQuery.from("Products")
    .where("Category.CategoryName", "startswith", "S")

// Orders sold to a Customer located in California
var query2 = EntityQuery.from("Orders")
    .where("Customer.Region", "==", "CA");
```

So, I think that in you code, the error can be in the next lines:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('title', 'contains', searchText)
            .or('displayname', 'contains', searchText);
```

It should be:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('title', 'contains', searchText)
            .or('user.displayname', 'contains', searchText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried all those variations already. Still no luck!

Comment: Could this have to do with foreign key constraints... or the lack of them?

Comment: No errors. What I've noticed is that there is no Network activity when I try the Predicate with displyname. This sends a Network request:    var pred = breeze.Predicate.create('title', 'contains', searchText);   ...... This one doesn't  ...   var pred = breeze.Predicate.create('user.displayname', 'contains', searchText);  ... or anything in the User table for that matter!

Comment: Maybe you have to add query = query.where(pred).expand('User');

Comment: is there something in you console as '[ ]'?

Comment: .expand('User') - Good idea but it didn't change anything. I have actually already expanded this in the original query: var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Posts").expand("User"); There is really nothing coming back in the console at all:

Comment: Creating datacontext ngLogger.js:15
Getting Posts ngLogger.js:15
getting all datacontext.js:48
Getting Posts ngLogger.js:15
getting all datacontext.js:48
searchText app.js:20
2
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/WordPress2.svc/$metadata". datajs-1.1.1beta.js:2608
2
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/WordPress2.svc/Posts?$expand=User". datajs-1.1.1beta.js:2608
Retrieved 3 ngLogger.js:15
Retrieved 3 ngLogger.js:15
[Object, Object, Object]
 app.js:58
[Object, Object, Object]
 app.js:58
Getting Posts ngLogger.js:15
searching for bob ngLogger.js:15
Should be empty: [] q.js:656
searchText

Comment: There is an error, but it is captured for breeze or other library, so the only thing that show you that an error ha been throw is that: "Should be empty: []". I recommed you, to put some break points in your code using the dev tools of chrome and follow the diferent call until you ca get the error.

Comment: You were right - Should be empty: [] indicates an error. I got the debugger in Webstorm working and found that when it makes this request - http : // localhost/WordPress2.svc/Posts?$filter=substringof('bob'%2CUser%2FDisplayName)%20eq%20true&$expand=User - I get this back in the promise stack - at <error: illegal access>.

Comment: I tried the url directly in a browser and got a bunch of php warnings instead of the expected xml. I guess this must mean that the php producer for oData doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out jvrdelafuente is right... the correct format for referencing the related table in oData with breeze would be (in the Wordpress example) user.displayName. The problem I have is that the odata producer for php (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/odataphpprod/) has a bug and returns errors. It's a shame that this project has been abandoned as I am sure plenty of people could benefit from it. It does not yet support Create, Update or Delete.

Thanks jvrdelafuente for your help.